# How to cancel keypress in js?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JavaScript. I have a question. When there are more than 160 characters, I do not want to type characters. How can I solve this problem?

```html
<body> <textarea onkeypress="olay()" id="twitter" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br>
    <div id="sonuc"></div>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    i = 0;

    function olay() {
        i += 1;
        if (i > 160) {
            document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = "Warning. Over 160 character";
            document.getElementById("twitter").addEventListener("onkeypress", function(event)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        } else {
            document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = "Numver of charecter : " + i;

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you want to create a field that has a maximum of 160 characters.

Comment: thanks, but I want to limit it with JavaScript.

Comment: I added how to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: I updated my solutions you should check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need JavaScript; text inputs have a [`maxlength` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength).

```
<textarea
    onkeypress="olay()"
    id="twitter"
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    maxlength="160"></textarea>
```

Comment: @KasimŞEN* **Why?**  `maxlength` is built into HTML and works with [every browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=maxlength)

Comment: Hmm okay, I'm just trying to find out the limits of JavaScript.Thank you.

Comment: @KasimŞEN: You can do it with JavaScript, but it’s rather complicated (have to save the location of the selection, cut the text off, and put the selection back – there are more ways to put text in a textarea than with the keyboard, like right-click paste) and there’s no point.

Comment: @KasimŞEN Or he can simply save previous input and put it back in if recent change caused value.length > 160.

Comment: @HaLeiVi: Still have to restore the selection.

Comment: Why? Onchange, replace the value.

Comment: @HaLeiVi: If the cursor inserting the text is anywhere except at the end…

Answer (score 0):

This is with html

```
<textarea 
id="twitter"
cols="30" 
rows="10" 
maxlength="160" 
placeholder="Enter text here...">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This how you would do it with JavaScript and HTML.**

```
<body>
    <textarea id="twitter" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="160" placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea><br>
    <div id="sonuc"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function olay() {
        var text = document.getElementById("twitter").innerHTML;
        var i = text.length;
        if (i >= 160) {
            document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = "Warning. Reached 160 character limit.";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = "Number of charecter : " + i;
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
        olay();
    });
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
        olay();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

the best you can do is write a regex and check every time on keypress.